# savedInstanceState when restoring fragment from back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, back-stack

Can I use `savedInstanceState()` to save the state when removing a fragment, then restore the state when I pop the fragment off the back stack?  When I restore the fragment from the back stack, savedInstanceState bundle is always null.

Right now, the app flow is: fragment created -> fragment removed (added to back stack) -> fragment restored from back stack (savedInstanceState bundle is null).

Here is the relevant code:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    Long playlistId = bundle.getLong(Constants.PLAYLIST_ID);
    int playlistItemId = bundle.getInt(Constants.PLAYLISTITEM_ID);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       selectedVideoNumber = playlistItemId;
    } else {
       selectedVideoNumber = savedInstanceState.getInt("SELECTED_VIDEO");
    }
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(Constants.SELECTED_VIDEO, selectedVideoNumber);
    }
```

I think the problem is that `onSavedInstanceState()` is never called when being removed and being added to back stack.  If I cant use onsavedInstanceState(), is there another way to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

onSaveInstanceState is (unfortunately) not called in normal back-stack re-creation of a fragment.  Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating and the answer on [How can I maintain fragment state when added to the back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353075/how-can-i-maintain-fragment-state-when-added-to-the-back-stack)

Answer (score 5):

I like to store the View I return in onCreateView as a global variable and then when I return I simply check this:

```
if(mBaseView != null) {
        // Remove the view from the parent
        ((ViewGroup)mBaseView.getParent()).removeView(mBaseView);
        // Return it
        return mBaseView;
    }
```

Comment: not sure this is a good idea.  Does this defeat the purpose of destroying the view to free memory if you save a reference to it?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, as I haven't run any direct tests. However, my thinking goes like this. When you initialize all the elements in your layout, it's standard to set most of those elements as a global variables, so if in the above example I couldn't recycle the base View because of the reference, Android wouldn't be able to recycle any of these Views either, thus leading to the same issue with memory.

Comment: This won't work if you need different views to be inflated for different orientations.

Comment: This solution saved my life.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the fragment needs to have an `Id` or `Tag` associated with it in order for the `FragmentManager` to keep track of it.

There are at least 3 ways to do this:

1. In xml layout declare an `Id` for your fragment:

   ```
   android:id=@+id/<Id>
   ```
2. If your fragments container `View` has an `Id`, use [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment)):

   ```
   FragmentTransaction  add (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)
   ```
3. If your fragment is not associated with any `View` (e.g. headless fragment), give it a `Tag`:

   ```
   FragmentTransaction  add (Fragment fragment, String tag)
   ```

[Also, see this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552273/1290264)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I hit this as well, but in my case onSaveInstanceState was called properly and I pushed in my state data when a new activity fragment was brought up on the smartphone.  Same as you, the onActivityCreated was called w/ savedInstanceState always null.  IMHO, I think it's a bug.

I worked around it by creating a static MyApplication state and putting the data there for the equivalent of "global variables"...