# Saving State of Fragments in a FragmentActivity with FragmentTabHost

Tags: android

I have a Fragment Activity with a FragmentTabHost. I add the fragments to the tab using the following code:

```
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tab1Name).setIndicator(tabIndicator1),
            EventSettingsStep1Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tab2Name).setIndicator(tabIndicator2),
            EventSettingsStep2Fragment.class, null);
```

When I switch to different tabs, I'd like to retain all the values (view state, etc) so that I have the same data when I switch back to the tab.

I overrode the onSaveInstanceState method & in there, I added values that I want retained to the bundle.

I ran through the methods being called and I have the following:

Switching from Tab1 to Tab2: Tab1:onPause then Tab2:onCreateView, Tab2:onResume

Switching from Tab2 to Tab1: Tab2:onPause then Tab1:onCreateView, Tab1:onResume

onSaveInstanceState is not being called.

Here is the code for one of my fragments:

```
public class EventSettingsStep1Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "restoring onSavedInstanceState");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        event = gson.fromJson(savedInstanceState.getString("event"), Event.class);
    }


    if (event != null) {
        //set views 

    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    outState.putString("event", gson.toJson(event));
}
```

}

Why is onSaveInstanceState not being called? Is it only triggered through the FragmentActivity?

Answer (score 2):

onSaveInstanceState is not being called because the framework simply reuses the already-existing instance of the fragment. onSaveInstanceState only gets called when the instance is about to be destroyed and then recreated. This happens for example when you rotate the display and force the hosting activity to be recreated.

onSaveInstanceState is also not called when you push a fragment on the backstack of a FragmentManager. You will have to restore the state from the already existing instance, which can be very annoying. See SO questions [How can I maintain fragment state when added to the back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353075/how-can-i-maintain-fragment-state-when-added-to-the-back-stack) and [Once for all, how to correctly save instance state of Fragments in back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack) for example.

Basically you will have to do what the answers to these questions suggest: continue using the values of your instance variables and do not rely on a saved instance state.