# savedInstanceState is null in onCreateView for Fragment when return from another activity not when return from other apps

Tags: android, android-fragments

**UPDATE**

The only workaround I was able to find was to create a `static` variable and store the state in there. This is not a good solution, but it works.

I tried saving the state in the Activity but the Activity's `onRestoreInstanceState` was never called.

---

I am **not** using `setRetainInstance()`.

When on a fragment and I rotate the device or multi-task to another app and then come back, the `savedInstanceState` is **not** null in `onCreateView`. **BUT** when I stay in the app and click an item in the fragment's `ListView` and use an Intent to show a different activity and then hit the back button to return to the original activity (which shows my fragment), then it **is** null! Why?

**NOTE: The answer in this [How can I maintain fragment state when added to the back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353075/how-can-i-maintain-fragment-state-when-added-to-the-back-stack) did not work.** My instance variables are in their default states when I return from the other activity.

```
//It is a android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Only shows null when returning from another Activity IN this app
    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "NULL?" + savedInstanceState);

    return createMyView();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //Save some value (It is NOT null here)
    outState.putInt("TestKey", "saved_key" );

    //Save the state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    //This is never null, so should be ok
    Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Outstate : " + outState);
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //SavedInstanceState is NULL here too (when returning from within same app)!
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Why is it null when returning from another Activity but not when returning from other apps?

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` is not called when you switch between activities

Comment: @blackbelt yes, it is. I have a log statement in there and it runs. But even ignoring that, I try saving to instance variables but these are all null (default state) in `onCreateView`.

Comment: did you solved this problem I am encountering this too

Comment: @NeonWarge if you look at my post, you'll see there's an update with a workaround. That's all I ever found