# Refresh value in editext using addToBackStack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragment, "A" and "B".

When I return (BackPressed) to my fragment "A", the values of edittext aren't refresh. Why?

I have this code to call fragment "B".

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container_pedido_novo,
            container, false);

    btnAddProduto = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNovoProduto);
    btnAddProduto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new FragmentContainerProduto(true);
            FragmentManager frgManager = getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager();
            frgManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    });

    edtCodPedido = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtCodPedidoNovo);
    edtVlBruto = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtVlBrutoPedidoNovo);

    edtCodPedido
            .setText(String.valueOf(GlobalUtil.objPedido.getCodPedido()));
    edtVlBruto.setText(String.valueOf(GlobalUtil.objPedido.getVlBruto()));

    return view;
}
```

Someone?

Answer (score 0):

When you return to a fragment from the back stack Android does not re-create the fragment but re-uses the same instance of it and starts with `onCreateView()` in the fragment lifecycle. The key thing is you should not inflate view again in `onCreateView()` of the fragment to which you return, because you are using the existing fragment instance. You need to save and reuse the rootView. See here the answer of Vince Yuan [How can I maintain fragment state when added to the back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353075/how-can-i-maintain-fragment-state-when-added-to-the-back-stack).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just need put this code...

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    edtVlBruto.setText(String.valueOf(GlobalUtil.objPedido.getVlBruto()));
    edtCodPedido
            .setText(String.valueOf(GlobalUtil.objPedido.getCodPedido()));
}
```