# Lost ImageButton resource and Listener after change Tabs and return

Tags: android, android-fragments, imagebutton

I have an application that have 3 swipe Tabs and in the first Tab Fragment I have created a Imagebutton.
I click on the ImageButton and change the Image resource.
When swipe to the second Tab and return the image resource remain ok, but if I swipe to the 3 tab and return to the first the ImageButton are changed to the original state and the listener are lost (if I try to click on the ImageButton, no clicklistener are active!)

this is my code:
**EDIT UPDATE CODE**

```
@Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        }

    @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container, false);
                setRetainInstance(true);
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView step 1");
                if(btn == null)
                    btn = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnP1C1R1);
                btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
        return rootView;
            }

    @Override
            public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated step 2");

            }

    @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated step 3"); 
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                appContext = getActivity().getBaseContext();
                appContextDialog = getActivity();
                GappContext = appContext.getApplicationContext();      
            }

    ImageButton.OnClickListener listener = new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                btn.setImageResource( R.drawable.delete_64 );
                Toast.makeText(appContext, "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

the sequence is:
Pagina3﹕ onCreate step 0
Pagina3﹕ onCreateView step 1
Pagina3﹕ onViewCreated step 2
Pagina3﹕ onActivityCreated step 3
Pagina3﹕ On Start
Pagina3﹕ On Resume .....
Pagina1﹕ On Pause .....
Pagina1﹕ On Stop .....
Pagina1﹕ onCreateView step 1
Pagina1﹕ onViewCreated step 2
Pagina1﹕ onActivityCreated step 3
Pagina1﹕ On Start
Pagina1﹕ On Resume .....
Pagina3﹕ On Pause .....
Pagina3﹕ On Stop .....
```

Page1 is the Fragment on the Tab1 and Page3 is The fragment on Tab3.
How can solve it?

**I HAVE SOLVED with this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23533575/4567295):**

Comment: Try setting the `onClick` attribute in the button's xml layout file instead.

Comment: It's because it replaces the fragment and it's values are cleared. Try saving the values in `sharedPrefrences` and set them in the `onCreateView` of that fragment. Your next question: then why didn't it happen on 2nd tab? Well, it maintains the fragment left and right of the current opened tab, that's why.

Comment: I have update the code, but I have to save the ImageButton variable?
I have to parcel it?