# How to save only the first fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had created a frame layout at my Main Activity and added fragment 1 into the layout when the app launch.

```
Fragment fr;
fr = new fragment1();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

After this when the user presses something on Fragment 1, it will start fragment 2.

```
Fragment2 newFragment = new Fragment2();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

The problem now is when I press back button on fragment 2, it will back to fragment 1 but reload fragment 1.  And when I press back button again, it will back to fragment 2 again.  Anyone can help me on this question as I only want fragment 1 to be saved at all the time and fragment 2 is destroy when the user presses the back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you add a fragment to the activity for the first time you need write
>   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_place, fr) instead of fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);

You are initializing fragment 1 from MainActivity for the first time so your code looks something like this

```
Fragment fr;
fr = new fragment1();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**You see that I also remove fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); from my code.**

**Because**

> You said that when you go to fragment 1 and press back button it return back to fragment 2. That's because you add fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); to the first fragment fragment. So when you come back to fragment 1, android add fragment 2 in back stack of fragment 1. So when you press back button it returns back to fragment 2.

And when you going to another fragment from a fragment then you need to use fragmentTransaction.replace();

Your final code look like this

```
Fragment fr;
fr = new fragment1();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And

```
Fragment2 newFragment = new Fragment2();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> And when i press back button again, it will back to fragment 2 again.

This happen because when you load fragment 2, you added it into backstack, so remove this line of code

```
Fragment2 newFragment = new Fragment2();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, newFragment);
//transaction.addToBackStack(null); <-- remove this
transaction.commit();
```

> The problem now is when i press back button on fragment 2, it will
>   back to fragment 1 but reload fragment 1.

If you return to a fragment from the back stack it does not re-create the fragment but re-uses the same instance and starts with onCreateView() in the fragment lifecycle, see [Fragment Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating). This answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11353470/4910489)

Answer (score 0):

I find an easy way.  `kotlin code`:

```
    var fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
         fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frg_holder, yourNewFragment)
        .commit()
    else
        fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frg_holder, yourNewFragment)
        .addToBackStack("tag")
        .commit()
```