# Do not remove fragment from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I want to save `fragments` in manager, even if I click on back.
This is code:

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right_frag, R.anim.slide_out_left_frag, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.findFragmentByTag(title);

        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(title) == null) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, title);
            if (addToBackStack) {
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.show(manager.findFragmentByTag(title)).commit();
        }
```

now if I click `onBack` my `fragment` is removed from back stack and manager. I want to even if I click back save this fragment so If I click next I want to back to this fragment. 
This is my way:

```
frag1 -> clickOnNext -> frag2 -> put some data in edittexts ->
clickOnBack -> frag1 -> clickOnNext -> frag2(frag has data from first time).
```

Now always get new Instance of `fragment2`.

Comment: You can save fragment state by override method onSaveInstanceState(). have look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353075/how-can-i-maintain-fragment-state-when-added-to-the-back-stack

Answer (score 0):

Use `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, title);` instead of `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, title);`

And handle showing/hiding of fragments in your activity `onBackPressed` event.