# What is the advantage of using following pattern as described in developer docs

Tags: android, kotlin, design-patterns, coding-style, android-databinding

I was going through developer docs for Data binding. I found the following snippet:

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Can anyone let me know the principle and advantage of using two variables for binding which are used in same fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance, it seems like `lateinit` would be a more natural choice. However, the Fragment instance is still usable after `onDestroyView` since Fragment instances can be torn down and reattached later. `lateinit` won't let you change the parameter back into uninitialized state, so it's not suitable for this purpose.

Using `!!` can result in Kotlin NPEs, which is not great. I would suggest modifying the sample code to provide better documentation and error reporting, like this:

```
/** This property is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView. */
private val binding get() = _binding ?: 
    error("Binding is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView.")
```

But practically, your Fragment is not going to be so complicated that you would have trouble tracking down an error like this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`binding` is a non-null property with nullable backing field, so when you access it you don't have to constantly use `?` to check for nullability.

It will however throw `KotlinNullPointerException` if accessed when it's not valid as described by the comment.

Comment: lateinit would suit better instead of using duplicate variables right?

Comment: They're properties, not variables. This distinction is notable here because the additional property doesn't result in an additional backing field variable.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT
this solution will cause a memory leak, as pointed out by `IR42`, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59504797/12506486) is why

ORIGINAL ANSWER
null safety, but I think using `lateinit` is a better solution for that purpose

```
private lateinit var binding : ResultProfileBinding
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

Comment: even I felt lateint would be better

Comment: @Keshav1234 you should release `_binding` property in `onDestroyView`, you can't do that with `lateinit` property

Comment: @IR42 are you sure? in Google's [Sunflower app](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/GardenFragment.kt) they don't release it, and it's supposed to be a best practice for Jetpack

Comment: @Stachu and therefore they have a memory leak when you move from `GardenFragment` fragment to another `android.widget.FrameLayout instance
​ Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.GardenFragment received Fragment#onDestroyView() callback (references to its views should be cleared to prevent leaks) and View detached and has parent)` https://github.com/android/sunflower/issues/628