# Why not use lateinit modifier in Andrioid Fragment view-binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, fragment

In [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) we have example of view binding without `lateinit`:

```kotlin
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Why we are not using `lateinit`, like we use it in activity:

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

I suspect it has something with a memory leak problem. Can you explain it?

Comment: Interestingly, `private lateinit var binding` is used in [GardenFragment](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/GardenFragment.kt) of [sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower), the app Google created to illustrate the best practices of Android development with Android Jetpack. Is Google illustrating a  bad practice?

Answer (score 5):

I found a good explanation [here](https://engineering.procore.com/fix-your-android-memory-leaks-in-fragments).

Snippet from the explanation:

> How do leaks happen in fragments? First, we need to start by reviewing
> the important nuance of fragments. They have two different lifecycles:
>
> - It’s own lifecycle (`onCreate` and `onDestroy`)
> - It’s view’s lifecycle (`onCreateView` and `onDestroyView`)
>
> Having two lifecycles for a single
> screen can be problematic. They are created and destroyed at different
> times, for instance, when putting a fragment on the back-stack.
> Specifically, holding onto views after `onDestroyView` is called will
> leak. This happens when a fragment is on the back stack, and although
> its view is destroyed, the fragment itself is not. The garbage
> collector is unable to clear the reference to those views.

And one snippet from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503689/could-navigation-arch-component-create-a-false-positive-memory-leak/59504797#59504797) Stack Overflow answer:

> You have to null out your references to the views in `onDestroyView` as
> that's the sign that the view is no longer being used by the Fragment
> system and it can be safely garbage collected if it wasn't for your
> continued reference to the `View`.

Comment: Could you update this [link](https://engineering.procore.com/fix-your-android-memory-leaks-in-fragments)? Link seems to unavailable now.

Answer (score 0):

`binding` in fragments could lead to memory leaks, if they aren't set to null in `onDestroyView`. That's why we set `_binding` to `null` in `onDestroyView`

While on using `lateinit`, we cannot assign a `lateinit` property to `null`. So, if we use `lateinit binding` we won't be able to set it to null in `onDestroyView` and it would lead to `memory leak`. It is why android documentation recommends using a `nullable` variable.

In case of `activities` we don't need to assign `binding` to `null` as they don't lead to leak memory, and we can use a `lateinit` property for `binding`.

Comment: But why, can you explain with an example (scenario). This answer can be found on [internet](https://medium.com/default-to-open/handling-lifecycle-with-view-binding-in-fragments-a7f237c56832).

Comment: Everything that you said is the same as what the documentation says. Can you provide one scenario when a memory leak can occur? @praveen

Comment: Fragments outlive their views, if views are destroyed even then it could hold that binding reference.

Comment: It's not the traditional definition of memory leak. It's more like a temporary memory leak where the Fragment instance is hanging onto references to obsolete views that the OS wants to release because the Fragment is on the backstack.

Answer (score 0):

### Take a look at this example

```
// here a firestore database uses callback to be executed when the document recieved 
db.collection("cities").document("SF").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document != null) {
                binding.textView.text = document.data.toString()
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
            }
        }
```

if the user opened the fragment and closed it before the document received (that's mean the fragment no longer be used and should clear all it's variables by garbage collector if the variable is null or no longer used)

#### Now let's discuss what the scenario with `lateinit`

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding
```

the garage collector will not clear the `binding` as it still used in the callback and the fragment will remain in the memory which lead a memmory leak, then however the callback executed and set the text the user won't know about that because he left the fragment

**Imagine if the user did this scenario multiple times !!**

#### So what about nullable binding ?

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

you setting it to null in `onDestroyView` so the `binding` and fragment can be garbage collected (No Memory leaks)

BUT is what will happen when the callback executed?

you will get a `NullPointerException` so be aware of that

and whatever how many times the user open the fragment and closed it it will garbage collected

give yourself a try with this code, you can use [Android Studio Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) to watch device memory and/or [leakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/) to get notify about the app memory leaks

Comment: You should either a) do that work in your viewmodel and notify the fragment via a livedata or b) cancel the db job when destroying the fragment. If b is not possible then definitely a. This reminds me of AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct but am giving him an example of what could happen, am not providing a best practice or a clean code solution