# How to maintain fragment back stack when reloading activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on an application with multi-language support and I'm reloading my activity after changing app's language with this part of code in my settings fragment. (Unfortunately I can not use `recreate()` method to reload the activity)

```
activity.finish();
activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(activity.getIntent().putExtra("FromSettings", true));
activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

The problem with this approach is that the activity's fragments back stack gets removed and I can no longer go back to fragments before my settings fragment.

How can i maintain fragments back stack when reloading the activity?

Comment: See the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353075/how-can-i-maintain-fragment-state-when-added-to-the-back-stack

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen didn't help, what i want is to save the back stack and restore it in activity's next launch.

Comment: As far as I know, you might need to store the fragments opened locally and invoke the fragment manually when going back.. other SO'ers correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: the fragment manager manager the list of fragment and transactions if you can somehow keep the fragment of old activity during configuration change , then maybe you can use it access the back stack , and if you retain fragment they will be saved during configuration change but i do't know whether back stack also get saved you should check it.