# Fragments within a Fragment cannot retain their values

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-savedstate

I have an activity and in that activity I have 2 Fragments A and B.

**Fragment A** has a **EditText** for entering **Email**.

**Fragment B** contains **2** more fragments **B1** and **B2** which can be selected using two buttons at the bottom of Fragment B.

B1 and B2 contain an **EditText** for entering **Name** and **Number**.

When i enter Email, Name and Number and switch between fragments A and B, Email value retains **BUT** the Name and Number values in sub-fragments B1 and B2 gets lost.

Is it because i have nested fragments in B?

How can i retain the values of sub-fragments B1 and B2?

I am new to android, Can anybody refer a good working example?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550016/savedinstancestate-is-always-null-in-fragment/20552273#20552273

Answer (score 0):

It's always a pain working with 2+ fragments.

Not the best workaround:
Try using `SharedPreferences` to save and display Name and Number, and reload the entire activity when needed so that changes get effected.

Comment: As i am new with android so I was testing it with the text fields .... In reality i will displaying 2 different ListViews in Fragments  A and B. And i don't want my list views to loose the values.

Comment: Are you using tabs to switch between fragments?

Comment: I am selecting Fragment A and B from a menu which slides in from left, and Fragment B has two button at the bottom with which you can switch between sub-fragments B1 and B2.

Comment: i have found 2 solutions but don't know which one is efficient so would like your suggestions, please see the link, i appreciate your help so far.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275746/retain-fragment-with-show-hide-or-save-fragment-data-in-a-file-which-one-is-eff

Comment: In my project I used 'replace' a lot, to change fragments and ended up having many problems. So I would say go with the first solution.

Comment: what kind of problems you faced? because so far 'replace' is working perfectly.